# AND vs. OR with datetime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to exclude all leap days (February 29) from a column titled Date, which is in YYYY-MM-DD string format.  This is what I did:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df = df[(df['Date'].dt.day != 29) & (df['Date'].dt.month != 2)]
```

However, the results incorrectly excluded the whole of February for all years.

When I changed the AND operator (`&`) to OR (`|`), only February 29 was correctly excluded.  Why does this work?  I thought that I would need the AND operator to take into account the combination of month and day.

Comment: It's general logic, e.g [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) rather than a datetime issue. You want `NOT (day==29 and month==2)` That is `(NOT day==29) OR (NOT month==2)`. Think, for example, how your condition works for `03-29`?

Comment: Thank you, makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the logic now.  Consider February 25th as an example.

False (February) AND True (25th) = False,

which was why the result for all days in February evaluated to False.

Whereas,

False OR True = True,

which preserved results for days in February that weren't 29.